# Redux-Form is not connected to Router correctly

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm trying to `initialize` data into form, show the form and navigate to other component (manually). After I successfully load data into form I found myself in a dead end, that I am unable to navigate to another component because I am getting `TypeError: path.lastIndexOf is not a function` error.

I am using `redux-form` and component is `connect`ed via `withRouter`.

I tried to workaround it with changing to `React.Component`, but after I managed to get data into form and connect component with `Router`, data in the form was unable to change (I was unable to even interact with the form). So I switched back to old solution that gave me that error.

**Used versions**:

```
"react-redux": "^6.0.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
"redux-form": "^8.1.0",   
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
```

***userProfile.jsx***

```
const renderField = ({
  input,
  label,
  placeholder,
  type,
  meta: { touched, error },
  ...rest
}) => (
  <div>
    <label htmlFor={label}>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} {...rest} type={type} />
      {touched
        && ((error && <span className="error-text">{error}</span>))}
    </div>
  </div>
);

let userProfile = (props) => {
  const {
    handleSubmit, pristine, submitting, reset,
  } = props;
  const confirmTitle = 'Are you sure about clearing the changed values?';
  const confirmDescription = 'Please notice that you can lose the data you edited';
  return (
    <div className="container__form" style={{ height: '160vh' }}>
      <Confirm title={confirmTitle} description={confirmDescription}>
        { confirm => (
          <form className="extended-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h3> Personal Data </h3>
            <div className="form-control">
              <Field
                name="username"
                type="text"
                component={renderField}
                label="User name"
                disabled
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-control">
              <Field
                name="email"
                type="text"
                component={renderField}
                label="E-mail"
                disabled
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-control">
              <Field
                name="user.firstName"
                type="text"
                component={renderField}
                label="First Name"
                validate={required()}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-control">
              <Field
                name="user.lastName"
                type="text"
                component={renderField}
                label="Last Name"
                validate={required()}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <div className="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
          Submit
                </button>
                {/* </div>
              <div className="form-actions"> */}
                <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={confirm(() => reset())}>
          Cancel
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        )}
      </Confirm>
    </div>
  );
};

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(
    state => ({
      ...state,
      initialValues: state.user.data,
    }),
  ),
  reduxForm({
    form: 'userProfileForm',
    enableReinitialize: true,
  }),
)(userProfile);
```

***UserProfileComponent.jsx***

```
const UserProfileComponent = (props) => {
  const sendData = (data) => {
    props.clearErrors();
    props.updateUserData(data);
  };

  const { errors } = props;
  return (
    <div className="extended">
      <h2> Extended Register process </h2>
      <div className="tooltip"> i </div>
      <span className="pale-magenta-text"> The mandatory fills are indicated by a * in the right site of the field name </span>

      <UserProfile onSubmit={sendData} />
      <br />
      {errors && (<div className="error-text">{errors.error}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state,
  errors: state.errors,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  updateUserData: data => dispatch(updateUserData(data)),
  clearErrors: () => dispatch(clearErrors()),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(UserProfileComponent);
```

I expect `initialize` of the form to be working and also, that I am connected to the `Router` correctly.

The problem is I think in `HOC`, because when I change the order of `reduxForm` and `connect`, I can navigate but I cannot see any data initialized into form. But that's sadly my dead end I cannot move from. Thanks a lot for any help or suggestion.

Comment: The HOC you are using AFAIK composes from right to left and something goes wild there. Try `const RF = reduxForm(...)(userProfile)`  `export default (withRouter(connect(...)(RF))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a lot of debug and changes and finally I found a way how to make it all work.

It's maybe not the best answer, but it can help someone with the same problem:

1. I removed withRouter (as it was not needed anymore) and changed the order of HOC in **UserProfile.jsx** to match:

```
export default compose(
  reduxForm({
    form: 'userProfileForm',
    enableReinitialize: true,
  }),
  connect(
    state => ({
      ...state,
      initialValues: state.user.data,
    }),
  ),
)(userProfile);
```

2. I hard coded `initialValues` in **UserProfileComponent.jsx*** to match:

```
<UserProfile onSubmit={sendData} initialValues={props.user.data}/>
```

Now the data is loaded, user can interact with the form (validation is working) and also, user can fully navigate in the site with no errors.

I hope it helps someone to solve same or similar problem that I had.

Enjoy